# Python MSAL PATCH to mark email as read CompactToken parsing failed

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a program that utilizes the MS Graph API and pulls emails received yesterday that have an attachment and have not been read. My endpoint looks like this:

```
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$expand=attachments&$search="hasAttachments:true AND received:yesterday AND isRead:false"'
```

After I authenticate and pull the data needed, I'm sending the content bytes to an s3 bucket to store with this block below:

```
result = app.acquire_token_silent(config["scope"], account=a)
s3     = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = config['bucket']
for email in emails:
    if email['hasAttachments']:
        attachments = email['attachments']
        count = 0
        for attachment in attachments:
            if attachment['isInline'] is False:
                name = attachment['name']
                fileContent =  base64.b64decode(attachment['contentBytes'])
                s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=name, Body=fileContent)
                count = count +1
                emailid = email['id']
                rp      = requests.patch(f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{emailid}', data ={'isRead':'true'}, headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer token= {result['access_token']}"})
                print(rp)
                logger.info('Attachment uploaded-' + ' Attachment Size: ' + str(attachment['size']) + ' File Name: ' + attachment['name'] + ' Email Source: ' + email['from']['emailAddress']['address'] + ' Email ID: ' + email['id'] + ' Email Subject Line: ' + email['subject'])     
        logger.info(f"Attachment count uploaded to s3: {count}")
logger.info('All uploads complete')
```

Everything works fine, except I seem unable to mark the email as read so it doesn't get pulled again with another request.

This is the full error i'm getting:

```
'{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217","innerError":{"date":"2022-11-17T18:48:54","request-id":"<xxx>","client-request-id":"<xxx>"}}}'
```

I'm sure there is something wrong with my formatting or possibly an issue with the scopes i've given it. The only scope I have added currently is ["Mail.ReadWrite"].

Do I just have is formatted incorrectly, or is there something else going on here that's triggering the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
requests.patch(f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{emailid}', json={'isRead': True}, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {oauth_token_access_token}'})
```

Comment: This was close, I still had to end up reformatting it by removing token from the last argument. requests.patch(f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{emailid}', json={'isRead': True}, headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer " + result['access_token']})

Comment: You're right sorry I missed that one. So in total there were 3 points to adjust: the data param becomes json, the isRead becomes a boolean and the format of the authorization bearer string. I updated the answer for future reference.